# Is there any way to save multiple svg from one svg?

Tags: svg, icons, inkscape

I'm designing an icon pack in Inkscape. I have like 70 icons in one SVG file. Can I export each one in a separate SVG file? If it's not possible in Inkscape, I'm open to using Illustrator or any proprietary software. Thanks for help guys.

Comment: There is a related question here: [Save multiple objects from vector file to separate files using Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51592/save-multiple-objects-from-vector-file-to-separate-files-using-inkscape-os-freew)

Comment: I've written a node library that covers that use case: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-icon-toolbox